# Ayuda con QT designer y PyQt5 con el modulo uic

Tags: python, qt, interfaz-gráfica, pyqt5

Tengo un problema al intentar desarrollar un GUI con PyQt5 y QT desginer.

Quiero usar el módulo `uic`, tengo un archivo .ui llamado `registro.ui`, y otro `login.ui`, ¿como puedo llamar desde `login.ui` a la ventana `registro.ui`, haciendo un click en el boton registro utilizando solo el metodo `uic.loadUI()` ?

Tengo estas 2 clases `login.py` y `registro.py` ambos tienen sus respectivos archivos .ui

**Clase login:**

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5 import uic
import Con_pos
from Registro import Registro
class Login(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Login.ui", self)
        self.registro.clicked.connect(self.view_Registro)
        self.ingresar.clicked.connect(self.autenticar)

    def autenticar(self):
        pid = self.getPID()
        con = Con_pos.con_pos()
        user = self.in_login.text()
        password = self.in_pass.text()
        print(password)
        fecha = time.strftime("%X") + " " + time.strftime("%x")
        if user != "" and password != "":
            consulta = ''' SELECT "id_user" FROM "User" WHERE "id_user" = '%s' ; ''' %(user)
            c_user = con.consulta(consulta)
            print(c_user)
            consulta = ''' SELECT "pass" FROM "User" WHERE "id_user" = '%s' ;''' %(user)
            c_pass = con.consulta(consulta)
            if c_user != None:
                c_pass = c_pass[0]
                print("test")
                print(c_pass)
                if c_pass == password:
                    consulta = ''' INSERT INTO "sesion" VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s'); '''%(fecha ,pid, user)
                    con.insertar(consulta)
    def getPID(self):
        con = Con_pos.con_pos()
        func = "pg_backend_pid"
        pid = con.call_proc(func)
        pid = pid[0][0]
        return pid

    def view_Registro(self):
        pass
        reg = Registro.Registro()
        reg.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Clase Registro:**

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic
import Con_pos
import error_log as error

class Registro(QMainWindow):
    con = Con_pos.con_pos()
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Registro.ui", self)
        self.btn_reg.clicked.connect(self.validar_nombre)

    def validar_nombre(self):
        fecha = time.strftime("%X") + " " + time.strftime("%x")
        usuario = self.user_tx_input.text()
        password = self.pass_tx_input.text()
        if usuario != "":
            pid = self.getPID()
            consul = '''SELECT "id_user" FROM "User" WHERE "id_user" = '%s'; ''' % (usuario)
            res_con = Registro.con.consulta(consul)

            if not res_con:
                ins_user = '''INSERT INTO "User" VALUES ('%s', '%s') ''' % (usuario, password)
                ins_sesion = ''' INSERT INTO "sesion" VALUES ('%s', %s,'%s') ''' % (fecha, pid, usuario)
                Registro.con.insertar(ins_user)
                Registro.con.insertar(ins_sesion)
            else:
                err = error.error_dia()
                err.etiqueta.setText("El usuario %s ya esta en uso" % (usuario))
                err.exec()

    def getPID(self):
        func = "pg_backend_pid"
        pid = Registro.con.call_proc(func)
        pid = pid[0][0]
        return pid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Registro()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def __init__(self):
    from Registro import Register
    QWidget.__init__(self)
    uic.loadUi("Login.ui", self)
    self.registro.clicked.connect(self.view_Registro)
    self.ingresar.clicked.connect(self.autenticar)
```

Donde Register es una Clase dondo invocas a la ventana de registro: `uic.loadUI()`